# Pointwise convergence topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Let $X=\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$. For $f\in X, x\in \mathbb{R}, \delta \gt 0$ we define $B_{f,x,\delta}:=\{g\in X : |g(x)-f(x)|\lt\delta\}$.
>
> a) Find a base for the weakest topology $\tau$ containing all the $B_{f,x,\delta}$.
> b) Show that $(X,\tau)$ is Hausdorff.
> c) Show that convergence in $(X, \tau)$ is equivalent to the usual pointwise convergence.

a) Clearly the $B_{f,x,\delta}$ cover $X$, but they are not closed under intersection. So let $A$ be the set of all finite intersections of the $B_{f,x,\delta}$. $A$ still covers $X$ and now it is a base, inducing a topology $\tau$ on $X$. $\tau$ is the weakest topology containig all the $B_{f,x,\delta}$ since a topology containing the $B_{f,x,\delta}$ must contain their finite intersection, thus also $A$, and $\tau$ is the weakest topology containing $A$.

b) Let $f,g\in X, f\ne g$. Then $f(x)\ne g(x)$ for at least one $x$. Fix such an $x$. Define $\delta := |f(x)-g(x)|$ now $B_{f,x,\delta/3}$ and $B_{f,x,\delta/3}$ are open, contain $f$ and $g$ respectively and have empty intersection by the triangle inequality. Thus $(X,\tau)$ is Hausdorff.

c) Let $x\in X, \delta\gt 0$. Let $f_k$ converge to $f$ in $\tau$. $B_{f,x,\delta}$ is an open neighborhood of $f$, thus there is a $k_0\gt 0$ such that for all $k\ge k_0: f_k\in B_{f,x,\delta}$. But this immediately gives the usual convergence by the definition of $B_{f,x,\delta}$.
For the other direction: Consider the sets of the form $B_{g,x,\delta}$ that contain $f$. Take $0\lt\epsilon\lt \delta - |g(x)-f(x)|$. Then by definition of pointwise convergence there is a $k_0\gt0$ such that for all $k\ge k_0: |f_k(x)-f(x)|\lt\epsilon$. Then by triangle inequality $f_k\in B_{g,x,\delta}$ for all $k\ge k_0$. So if $U$ is an open neighborhood of $f$, it will be a union of finite intersections of such $B_{g,x,\delta}$ containing $f$. For each of these $B_{g,x,\delta}$ we can take a $k_0$ high enough such that the $f_k$ will be contained in it. Then simply take the maximum of these, so all $f_k$ but finitely many will be contained in the sets that $U$ is a union/intersection of, thus also in $U$.

Are my proofs correct? And more importantly, is there a more elegant way to prove the second direction of c)?

Comment: Re the first direction/paragraph of c), switch the first two sentences, and change "$x \in X$" to "$x\in \mathbb{R}$", which is what you mean :)

Comment: Re the $\Leftarrow$ direction of c), is it that involved? Doesn't "the usual pointwise convergence" $f_n \xrightarrow{pointwise} f$ mean: for every $x, f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$? The topology $\tau$ is just the product topology, i.e. the least topology such that the projection functions $p_x\colon f \mapsto f(x)\colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous.

Comment: A more convenient base is $B(f; F; \delta) = \{ g \in X: \forall x \in F: |f(x) - g(x)| < \delta \}$, where $F$ ranges over all finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, and all $\delta > 0$, and all $f \in X$. This makes the proof of a) a bit more complex, and that of c) easier.